# Resize my image on upload not working - what must my buffer be?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, buffer

This is the code i got from [This Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/29645.aspx)

I want the user to upload a picture and then resize it.............

```
Public Sub ResizeFromStream(ByVal ImageSavePath As String, ByVal MaxSideSize As Integer, ByVal Buffer As System.IO.Stream)

    Dim intNewWidth As Integer
    Dim intNewHeight As Integer
    Dim imgInput As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Buffer)


    'Determine image format
    Dim fmtImageFormat As ImageFormat = imgInput.RawFormat

    'get image original width and height
    Dim intOldWidth As Integer = imgInput.Width
    Dim intOldHeight As Integer = imgInput.Height

    'determine if landscape or portrait
    Dim intMaxSide As Integer

    If (intOldWidth >= intOldHeight) Then
        intMaxSide = intOldWidth
    Else
        intMaxSide = intOldHeight
    End If

    If (intMaxSide > MaxSideSize) Then
        'set new width and height
        Dim dblCoef As Double = MaxSideSize / CDbl(intMaxSide)

        intNewWidth = Convert.ToInt32(dblCoef * intOldWidth)
        intNewHeight = Convert.ToInt32(dblCoef * intOldHeight)

    Else

        intNewWidth = intOldWidth
        intNewHeight = intOldHeight
    End If
    'create new bitmap
    Dim bmpResized As Drawing.Bitmap = New Drawing.Bitmap(imgInput, intNewWidth, intNewHeight)

    'save bitmap to disk
    bmpResized.Save(ImageSavePath, fmtImageFormat)

    'release used resources
    imgInput.Dispose()
    bmpResized.Dispose()
    Buffer.Close()

End Sub
```

Now when i click on my submit button it must execute my code but i am not sure what the input must be for the Buffer field?

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click() Handles btnUpload.Click

     ResizeFromStream("~Pics", 200, ??????????)

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I need to get my Image from the File Upload control!

Comment: Well where would you want the image data to come from?

Comment: From my file upload control called FileUpload1

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a stream object like this:

```
Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\file.jpg", FileMode.Open)

ResizeFromStream("~Pics", 200, fs)
```

So the code would be performing IO on the file 'file.jpg'. This is a very rough example, but as Jon Skeet asked, the location of where the image is coming from does matter. My example is just simple 'get you started' type.

Comment: But i want to get it from my FileUpload control called FileUpload1

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the FileUpload control, but can't you use:
FileUpLoad1.SaveAs("C:\" & FileUpLoad1.FileName)
Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\" & FileUpload1.FileName", FileMode.Open)

ResizeFromStream("~Pics", 200, fs)

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload.FileContent get's a stream for the file content.

Comment: So you saying i must do this inside my btnUpload_Click method? 

ResizeFromStream("~Pics", 200, myFile.FileContent)

Because when i do this nothing is happening, file does not get uploaded.

Comment: Yes.

You forgot to put in a filename.
ResizeFromStream("~Pics\FILENAME.JPG", 200, myFile.FileContent)

(You can get the original filename from FileUpload I think)

Comment: Yes, from FileUpload.FileName. So ResizeFromStream(Path.Combine("~Pics", FileUpload.FileName), 200, myFile.FileContent)